# Compare multiple rasters with consideration to order over time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, time-series

I have multiple land cover rasters for each year (i.e. 2002, 2003, 2004...etc.) and each of them have five land cover classes. I would like to set up evaluation rules in ModelBuilder.

An example of a rule would be: can't have class 2 or 3 and then have class 1. To clarify, if 2002 had a value of 1, and 2003 had a value of 2, and then 2004 had 1 again, this would be flagged.

I tried the combine tool, to have all the years in one single raster, and then evaluate across the fields.

Is there a way to achieve the above scenario?

The important distinction here is that anytime a sequence like 1-2-1 or 1-3-1 occurs, no matter the years, I'd like to identify it.

Comment: Combine is your tool. You tried and what happened?

Comment: How do you go about doing a conditional on the value of the combine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add field, type integer to attribute table of your combined raster and run this field calculator expression on it:

```
def findOnes(aList):
 n=len(aList); found=0
 for i in range(1,n-1):
  mid=aList[i]
  if mid==1:continue
  left=aList[i-1]
  if left!=1:continue
  right=aList[i+1]
  if right!=1:continue
  found=1;break
 return found
#---------------------
findOnes([ !ONE_A!, !ONE_B!, !ONE_C!, !ONE_D!, !ONE_E!])
```

You can use extract by attributes tool from Spatial Analyst, to create new raster:

[image]

Comment: Hi FelixIP, your solution was most helpful! It worked beautifully. I was wondering if there is a way to indicate which position this change occurred? Taking an example from your table, the first record flagged, is there a way to return "3" since it happened in "one_c", the third year in this sequence?

Comment: Replace found=0 by -1, found =1 by found=i+1